# Multiple objects to particles

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

Is there any way to add multiple objects to a particle simulation (emitter) without having to join the objects before adding them to the sim?

Comment: Is there a reason you've put rigid-body-simulation as tag on your question? Are those multiple objects you want to emit rigid bodies?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all objects you want to emit in one collection. In the *Render* settings of the *Particle System* you can choose *Collection* which will use all the objects in this collection.

By default, it's picking single objects to be emitted as particle. But you can check *Whole Collection* which means, each emitted particle will then consist off all objects in this collection in their relative positions like they are placed to each other.

For emitting single objects of the collection you can also check *Pick Random*, although it already looks random to me without this enabled.

Another setting you might want to use is *Use Count*, there you can specify if some of those picked should appear more often than others from the collection.

[image: particle collection]

Answer (score -1):

When you create a particle system for the second emitter, click on where it says "ParticleSettings.002". It will bring up a menu, and you can select your other particle system. They will be linked, and have the same particle system without being connected.

Comment: I don't think that was the question. Adding multiple objects to a particle simulation is not adding a particle simulation to multiple objects.